# Ошибка сериализации и десериализации бинарного файла(C#)

Tags: c#

Всем доброго времени суток, написал 2 метода 1-й сериализации, 2-й - десериализации, и при десериализации получаю следующие исключение:

> Не удалось привести тип объекта "System.Int32" к типу
>   "binary.Classes.Serializ".

```
[Serializable]
    class Serializ
    {
        public Int32 Line { get; set; }

        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        public void SerializSave (Int32 _line)
        {
            Line = _line;

            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"E:\DELETE\nr.dat", FileMode.Append))
            {
                formatter.Serialize(fs, Line);

                Console.WriteLine("Объект сериализован");
            }
        }

        public void SerializRead()
        {
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"E:\DELETE\nr.dat", FileMode.Open))
            {
                Serializ _serial = (Serializ)formatter.Deserialize(fs);

                Console.WriteLine("Объект десериализован");

                Console.WriteLine("Прочитано: {0}", _serial.Line);
            }
        }
    }
```

Как исправить ошибку данного характера ? что я не так сделал ? спасибо

Спасибо за пример, но теперь я получаю такое исключение:

> Additional information: Тип
>   "System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter" в
>   сборке "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,

Пробовал и так `FileMode.Append` и так `FileMode.Create`
Странно что на этот раз не так? и еще хотел спросить `FileMode.Create` - даст мне дозапись данных в файл ? мне это важно. Спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Вы утверждаете или думаете что сериализируете и десериализируете один и тот же обьект - но это не так. Почему то же вы сериализируете Line который **Int32**, а десериализируете уже **Serializ** конечно вам всё правильно пишет: Int32 не совместим с Serializ. Или и там и там Int32 или Serializ. Вместо Line в Serialize вам нужно вписать this - "себя", т.е.

```
     using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"E:\DELETE\nr.dat", FileMode.Append))
        {
            formatter.Serialize(fs, this); // Поменять тут
            Console.WriteLine("Объект сериализован");
        }
```

Только Append мне не очень нравится. Я так "кусками" не пробовал сериализацию. Файл вам нужно точно очистить, т.к. уже сейчас он у вас не верный. Если десериализация даст сбой - прийдётся бить на куски с помощью MemoryStream. При Append нужно точно переделывать десериализацию, т.к. вы получите первый сериализированый обьект, и будете опять думать что не так. Лучше Create вместо Append.

Comment: Думаю, проблема именно в сериализации кусками. Наверняка сериализировать нужно всё скопом. Дозапись в файл не означает слияние потоков.

Answer (score -1):

Простой и универсальный способ сериализации. При этом ловит IO ошибки.

Пользуйся вот так:

```
[Serializable]
class Serializ
{
    public Int32 Line { get; set; }
    private filePath = @"E:\DELETE\nr.dat";

    public void SerializSave (Int32 _line)
    {
        Serializer.Save(filePath, _line);
        Console.WriteLine("Объект сериализован");   
    }

    public void SerializRead()
    {
        var asdf = Serializer.Load<Int32>(filePath);
        Console.WriteLine("Объект десериализован");
    }
}
```

Код класса:

```
public static class Serializer
{
    public static void Save(string filePath, object objToSerialize)
    {
        try
        {
            using (Stream stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                BinaryFormatter bin = new BinaryFormatter();
                bin.Serialize(stream, objToSerialize);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
        }
    }

    public static T Load<T>(string filePath) where T : new()
    {
        T rez = new T();

        try
        {
            using (Stream stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open))
            {
                BinaryFormatter bin = new BinaryFormatter();
                rez = (T) bin.Deserialize(stream);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
        }

        return rez;
    }
}
```